# Displaying an image from the tmp directory

Tags: php, linux

I have the following. A website that create temporarily images in the /tmp folder on the Linux server. The reason why I store it within this folder is since these images need to be cleared once in a while and it's so much easier just to clear the tmp directory using tmpwatch. Now my issue is to display the image within my browser?

Code

```
<img src="/tmp/3d34636.png" alt="image" />
```

I'm running Centos with PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble here, is that this img tag will be processed by the browser (the client). This client does not have access to the filesystem of the HTTP server.

Therefore, you have either to define the /tmp directory to be a valid location of your HTTP server, using the files in /tmp/ directory (but note that it would serve any other file contained in this directory, potentialy a security risk).

Or you store these generated images in a subdirectory that is already served by your HTTP server.

It may also be possible to define this /tmp location on the server to be served by a script that would analyse the URL containing the image filename. This script would then open the file in /tmp/ and serve it.

Comment: +1 storing this stuff in /tmp is really not a good idea; neither is making /tmp accessible to the public.

Comment: Or, option 3, you can have a PHP script that serves up the files from the /tmp directory, filtering as appropriate.

Comment: @psmears yup. But building that filter is probably more hassle than building a script that cleans up once in a while.

Answer (score 2):

@Didier already outlines the issue and the security risks. Even if you built a PHP script that accepts the file name as a parameter, and then passes through the file from the `/tmp` directory, you would be mixing public content with temp files that can contain sensitive data. You would have to keep a list of which files were generated by your script and are okay to display, and which ones are not, otherwise it would be a security hole.

I'd say forget `/tmp` for this despite the advantages, and store your images in a sub-directory of their own. Delete them frequently (e.g. using a cron job, or based on file age or the "last accessed" time).

Answer (score 1):

You can get tmpwatch to clean up another directory by creating a cron job that runs the command:

```
/usr/sbin/tmpwatch -umc 240 /path/to/directory
```

The `240` is the number of hours that the files haven't been used for before deletion (in this case 10 days). See `man tmpwatch` for full details.